# Works in VSC, fails in Heroku- ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

I'm receiving the below error that used to show up in both Visual Studio Code and in Heroku's logs.

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

After researching some other threads and articles, I figured it was my app.js going directly into the window function without regard for the browser/server distinction.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    readCSVFile('csvfile.csv');
    })
    
// ...rest of code...
```

The resulting VSC error (along with a similar error in Heroku):
VSC Debug Console:

```
/usr/local/bin/node ./app.js
Process exited with code 1
Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at <anonymous> (/Users/User/Documents/Code/herokuapp1/app.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at <anonymous> (internal/main/run_main_module:23:47)
app.js:3
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'
```

Following a suggestion in an [article about this error](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-referenceerror-window-is-not-defined), I tried incorporating an if/else statement:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('You are on the browser');
  
    // ✅ Can use window here
    console.log(window.innerWidth);

        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            readCSVFile('csvfile.csv');
            })
        //...rest of code...

  } else {
    console.log('You are on the server');
    // ⛔️ Don't use window here
  }
```

Fortunately, that tweak successfully resolved the error in VSC.
VSC Debug Console:

```
/usr/local/bin/node ./app.js
You are on the server
```

However, it did not resolve the error in Heroku. The commit is successful, the build is successful, but when I use the "Open App" function on the website, it fails.

Heroku logs, with timestamps removed:

```
...app[web.1]: /app/app.js:3
...app[web.1]: window.addEventListener('load', function() {
...app[web.1]: ^
...app[web.1]: 
...app[web.1]: ReferenceError: window is not defined
...app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:3:1)
...app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
...app[web.1]: at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
...app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
...app[web.1]: at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
...app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
...app[web.1]: at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

Have any of you encountered and solved this problem before?

UPDATE:
I had to go through my JavaScript file and rebuild with code compatible with Node.js.

There was no a quick fix to replacing all the browser-specific language with server-specific language, so tough lesson learned!

Comment: `window` only exists in browsers, not in server-side node.js.

Comment: @Barmar I just read up on the [node.js](https://nodejs.org) site. It sounds like I'll have to rebuild my code, replacing `window` with `global`. For example, using `global.addEventListener...` instead of `window.addEventListener`. Do you think this is the most effective route?

Comment: None of the things you're doing with `window` make sense on the server. There are no event listeners, there's no `innerWidth`. Those are all browser-specific.